# How do I make a BASH loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc

I'm very new to bash and Linux and I was wondering how I could make a bash loop so that when it runs, it will ask you how many times to run, and it will run that many times.

I did it in LUA but I want it to be in bash so it can be added to the `~/.bashrc` file so it starts when I connect to my VPS via ssh. Here is the lua code I wrote:

```
    write("How many times should I loop? ")
local Num = tonumber( read() )
for i=1,Num do
   print("Looped "..tostring(i).." time(s).")
end
```

Here is the little thing I will add to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]] ; then
echo example
fi
```

Comment: Note that, depending on your distribution, the `~/.bashrc` file won't be read when connecting via ssh. I would suggest you use `~/.profile` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner:

```
read -p "No of Repetitions?" repeat; for i in $(seq $repeat); do echo "This is $i"; done
```

If you want to run this if `$SSH_CONNECTION` is non-empty:

```
[[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]] && read -p "No of Repetitions?" repeat; for i in $(seq $repeat); do echo "This is $i"; done
```

- `&&` indicates to run the next command only if the previous one is successful (`$?=0`)
- `read -p "No of Repetitions?" repeat` will prompt `"No of Repetitions?"` and save the input as `repeat` variable.
- `for i in $(seq $repeat); do echo "This is $i"; done` this for loop will use `seq` to loop specified number of times to get the job done. You should replace `echo "This is $i"` with whatever operation you want to perform.

This can be elaborated as:

```
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
        read -p "No of Repetitions?" repeat
fi

for i in $(seq $repeat); do
        echo "This is $i" 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "How many times should I run? "
read numOfTimes
for i in $(seq 1 $numOfTimes);do
echo $i
done
```

Let's split the explanation into parts:

- **echo -n** presents the message in the screen and reads the user's
  response into variable **numOfTimes**.
- A bash **for loop** has the following structure:
  **for i in [1 2 3 4 ... n ]; do X; done**
- In this case, I create the sequence **1 2 3 4 ... n** using **seq**, to which you feed 1 as starting number and the last element, represented by the value of **$numOfTimes**.

Of course in a more complex scenario you should check whether the user's response is numeric and greater than zero, for example, but I think that this example will do the trick for what you want to accomplish.

Source: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html